# How to get informed about a mouse click on the picture in QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I show a picture inside `QTextEdit`. I want that after clicking on the thumbnail, a large full-screen picture opens.

This is how I output the picture:

```
ui->textEdit_in_out->textCursor().insertImage(img_toopen);
```

How to track a click on the picture?

Comment: Use `QTextBrowser` instead of `QTextEdit`, add link to the image and connect to the `QTextBrowser::anchorClicked` signal.

Comment: Did you try that? It would be nice to have a feedback.